# C: sum of integer values by string identifiers

Tags: c, hashtable, associative-array

So, I have two files of financial data, say 'symbols', and 'volumes'. In symbols I have strings such as:

```
FOO
BAR
BAZINGA
...
```

In volumes, I have integer values such as:

```
0001387
0000022
0123374
...
```

The idea is that the stock symbols will repeat in the file and I need to find the total volume of each stock. So, each row where I observe foo I increment total volume of foo by the value observed in volumes. The problem is that these files can be huge: easily 5 - 100 million records. A typical day may have ~1K different symbols in the file.

Doing it using strcmp on symbols each new line will be very inefficient. I was thinking of using an associative array --- hash table library which allows string keys --- such as `uthash` or `Glib`'s hashtable.

I am reading some pretty good things about `Judy arrays`? Is the licensing a problem in this case?

Any thoughts on the choice of an efficient hash-table implementation? And also, whether I should use hash tables at all or perhaps something else entirely.

Umm.. apologize for the omission earlier: I need to have a pure C solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

I did end up using the JudySL array to solve this problem. After some reading, the solution was quite simple to implement using Judy. I am replicating the solution here in full for it to be useful to anyone else.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Judy.h>

const unsigned int BUFSIZE = 10; /* A symbol is only 8 chars wide. */

int main (int argc, char const **argv) {

  FILE *fsymb = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  if (fsymb == NULL) return 1;

  FILE *fvol = fopen(argv[2], "r");
  if (fvol == NULL) return 1;

  FILE *fout = fopen(argv[3], "w");
  if (fout == NULL) return 1;

  unsigned int lnumber = 0;
  uint8_t symbol[BUFSIZE];
  unsigned long volume;

  /* Initialize the associative map as a JudySL array. */
  Pvoid_t assmap = (Pvoid_t) NULL;
  Word_t *value;

  while (1) {

    fscanf(fsymb, "%s", symbol);
    if (feof(fsymb)) break;

    fscanf(fvol, "%lu", &volume);
    if (feof(fvol)) break;

    ++lnumber;

    /* Insert a new symbol or return value if exists. */
    JSLI(value, assmap, symbol);
    if (value == PJERR) {
        fclose(fsymb);
        fclose(fvol);
        fclose(fout);
        return 2;
    }
    *value += volume;

  }

  symbol[0] = '\0'; /* Start from the empty string. */
  JSLF(value, assmap, symbol); /* Find the next string in the array. */
  while (value != NULL) {
    fprintf(fout, "%s: %lu\n", symbol, *value); /* Print to output file. */
    JSLN(value, assmap, symbol); /* Get next string. */
  }

  Word_t tmp;
  JSLFA(tmp, assmap); /* Free the entire array. */

  fclose(fsymb);
  fclose(fvol);
  fclose(fout);
  return 0;

}
```

I tested the solution on a 'small' sample containing 300K lines. The output is correct and the elapsed time was 0.074 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely hashtable sounds good. You should look at the `libiberty` implementation.
You can find it on the GCC project [Here](http://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk/libiberty/hashtab.c).

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Can you compare the libiberty implementation to uthash or Glib hash in terms of performance and memory consumption. I think I will specifically need a hash table that can use `string' keys.

Comment: I don't know about Uthash or Glib, but i have this [link](http://preshing.com/20110603/hash-table-performance-tests) bookmarked that can help you.

Comment: This link was quite helpful. Incidentally, I had been reading the same website earlier while researching the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use `Map` of `C++ STL`. Here's how the pseudo-code looks like:

```
map< string, long int > Mp;
while(eof is not reached)
{
    String stock_name=readline_from_file1();

    long int stock_value=readline_from_file2();

    Mp[stock_name]+=stock_value;
}
for(each stock_name in Mp)
   cout<<stock_name<<" "<<stock_value<<endl;
```

Based on the amount of data you gave, it may be a bit inefficient, but I'd suggest this because its much easier to implement.

If the solution is to be implemented strictly in `C`, then `hashing` will be the best solution. But, if you feel that implementing a hash-table and writing the code to avoid `collisions` is complex, I have another idea of using `trie`. It may sound weird, but this can also help a bit.

I would suggest you to read [this](http://simplestcodings.blogspot.com/2012/11/trie-implementation-in-c.html) one. It has a nice explanation about what a `trie` is and how to construct it. The implementation in C was also given there. So, you may have a doubt of where to store the `volumes` for each `stock`. This value can be stored at the end of the `stock string` and can be updated easily whenever needed.

But as you say that you are new to C, i advice you to try implementing using `hash table` and then try this one.

Comment: Hey, thanks. But I need a C solution. Not C++. I should have mentioned that in the question. Edited it just now.

Comment: Will you please post your idea of using tries? I am quite new to C programming. So a little bit of hand-holding will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking why not stick to your associative array idea. I assume, at the end of execution you need to a have list of unique names with their aggregated values. Below will work as far as you have memory to hold all unique names. ofcourse, this might not be that efficient, however, few tricks can be done depending upon the patterns of your data.

```
Consolidate_Index =0;

struct sutruct_Customers
{
name[];
value[];
}

sutruct_Customers Customers[This_Could_be_worse_if_all_names_are_unique]

void consolidate_names(char *name , int value)
{
    for(i=0;i<Consolidate_Index;i++){
        if(Customers[i].name & name)
            {
            Customers[i].value+= Values[index];

            }
    else
    {
    Allocate memory for Name Now!
    Customers[Consolidate_Index].name = name;
    Customers[Consolidate_Index].value = Value;
    Consolidate_Index++;
    }
    }
}

main(){

sutruct_Customers buffer[Size_In_Each_Iteration]

while(unless file is done){

file-data-chunk_names to buffer.name
file-data-chunk_values to buffer.Values

for(; i<Size_In_Each_Iteration;i++)
consolidate_names(buffer.Names , buffer.Values);

}
```

Comment: This is useful. I have only one question; how is this part of the code working: `if(Customers[i].name & name)`?